# How to make TextView height to wrap_content if it has 1 or 2 lines?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-constraintlayout

I have been struggling more than I would have expected on this, here is my issue.

As you can see on the image below, I want my `TextView` to be `center` `horizontally` in the `parent`, but also `align` `vertical` `center` with the view on the left.

[image]

The problem comes from the `TextView`, the text can be longer, I want it to be on 2 lines with the attribute `maxLength = 12`.

My XML:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/roundTextView"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/oval"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/descriptionTextView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descriptionTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:maxLength="12"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="Long Text 2 Lines"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/roundTextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/roundTextView" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If I change the text, with something longer (more than 10 length), here is the result, it's fine.

[image]

But if I change to a small text, the result is not as expected because of the `0dp` `height`. And if I put `wrap_content`, the 2 lines text isn't working.

[image]

What is the right way of handling this situation?

Comment: what is happening when adding wrap-content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding:

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:maxLines="2"
```

the text always is shown vertically in the middle and there is no need to `android:textAlignment="center"`.

Comment: This is the correct answer, thank you. Are you sure about the textAlignment ? I get a warning, but the text is not "centered". I will accept this answer in 5 minutes.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. If you want to show the text horizontally in the center too, use: `android:gravity="center"` instead.